# Equivalent forms of pullback

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let $\Lambda$ be an artin algebra. Here is a proposition[image]

Now I want to prove $(b)(iii) \Rightarrow (b)(ii)$:
The only problem is to show that $ker(g,g') \subseteq Im 
\binom{f}{-f'}$

Suppose $(b,b') \in ker (g,g')$, then $g(b)+g'(b')=0$. Then for any $a \in A$, $g(b+f(a))+g'(b'-f'(a))=0$. If $b \in Imf$, then I can get $b' \in Im f'$ and there is a $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=b$ and $f'(a)=b'$.

But I can't get $f$ is surjective, I don't know what to do next. Thank you for any help or hint.

Comment: Something seems to be missing from (iii). If $A=0$ and $B=B'=C$, with $g'=g=\mathrm{id}_C$, then $\ker f=\ker g'=0$ so $h$ is an isomorphism, but the pullback should be $C$.

Comment: @stewbasic This is a proposition of the book "Representation theory of artin algebras" at page 22.Your example is right.(maybe there are condtions lost, but I can't make sure)

Comment: Does the book say anything about the proof, or is it left as an exercise?

Comment: Maybe (iii) should additionally assert that $\mathrm{Coker}\,f\to\mathrm{Coker}\,g'$ is injective. (a)(iii) would need a similar change.

Comment: @stewbasic  It just gives the proposition, no proof, not exercise.

Comment: You might have an older version of the book. In my version, (iii) is not stated as equivalent but rather that if the diagram is pushout, then (iii) holds.

Comment: @Julian Kuelshammer Ok, maybe this is a mistake of the older version